# Drone.io Php Build Badges Always None

Tags: drone.io

I installed drone 0.4 version to aws and integrated with my private bitbucket repositories. Everyting is working as it should be. There is my .drone.yml file

```
build:
image: phpunit/phpunit
  cache:
    - vendor
  commands:
    - echo Building Started
    - composer install
    - phpunit
```

My commits are successfully build with unit tests, but my badges always looks like "build|none". Do I have to add anything else for that.

Thanks for help

Comment: An example build log would be helpful, however if it's showing as successful on Drone and the badge is displaying correctly in Bitbucket it seems odd it wouldn't show. 

Possible issues off the top of my head are if you have multiple instances of Drone behind an ELB, or possible caching.